# How to export a correct .json file

Tags: export, json-format

This is my current code:

```
testdata = <|"version" -> "5.3.0", "flags" -> <||>, 
   "shapes" -> {<|"label" -> "ob", 
      "points" -> {{1204.8260869565217`, 274.69565217391306`},
           {2211.3478260869565`, 392.0869565217391`}}, "shape_type" -> "polygon", 
      "flags" -> <||>|>}, 
   "imageData" -> "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA", 
   "imageHeight" -> 1832, "imageWidth" -> 3264|>;

Export["test1.json", testdata, "JSON"];
FilePrint["test1.json"]

Export["test2.json", testdata, "RawJSON"];
FilePrint["test2.json"]
```

[image]

Notice that both methods of exporting json files have problems:

1. The floating point number is a thousand times smaller
2. Those `"imageData"`  has a lot of extra `"\"`

How can I avoid these two problems in order to get the correct json file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Floating points are not smaller, they are written in the scientific notation: `1204.8 = 1.2048e3`.
2. Nothing wrong with that, it will be parsed correctly. Forward slashes are just being [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580647/14425096) by default (try `ImportString[ExportString[testdata, "JSON"], "JSON"]`).
3. You can use `ExportString[testdata, "JSON"]` instead of `Export` and `FilePrint`.

---

I want to stress again that the output is completely *correct* according to the specification, and any JSON parser should correctly read the file.

There doesn't seem to be any (un?)documented option to interfer with the output, so you have to do some manual adaptations to achieve what you want, namely:

1. Set the correct precision of the numbers*
2. Unescape slashes

```
exportJSON[expr_] := 
 StringReplace[
  ExportString[expr, "JSON", 
   ConversionRules -> {a_Real :> 
      SetPrecision[a, StringLength[ToString[InputForm[a]]] - 1]}], 
  "\\/" -> "/"]

exportJSON[testdata]
(* {
    "version":"5.3.0",
    "flags":{},
    "shapes":[
        {
            "label":"ob",
            "points":[
                [
                    1204.8260869565217,
                    274.69565217391306
                ],
                [
                    2211.3478260869565,
                    392.0869565217391
                ]
            ],
            "shape_type":"polygon",
            "flags":{}
        }
    ],
    "imageData":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA",
    "imageHeight":1832,
    "imageWidth":3264
} *)
```

<sub>* Compare `` ExportString[1000.`3, "JSON"] `` and `` ExportString[1000.`4, "JSON"] ``. There is probably a more elegant way to set the correct precision of the number than I did it in the code, but I am not very familiar with the details of precision handling in Mathematica ...</sub>

Comment: Hi, the is [Unprocessed raw json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTPqE.png), and this is [exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeWNC.png) by mma. I do not want to use scientific notation, and I do not want characters to be escaped, can I do that? If you can do that, I will choose your answer

Comment: @yode Take a look at the `ConversionRules` option http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/RawJSON.html

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier Could you post an answer about how to use `ConversionRules` for my these two demand?

Comment: @yode, please see the update.

Comment: @Domen Maybe the method based on Python makes life easier, see my answer in following...

Answer (score 1):

Post a method based on `Python`:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
(*Define python function for export*)
ExternalEvaluate[session, "import json

def exportjson(file,data):
    with open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)"]

(*Use the Python function in MMA*)
ExternalFunction[session, "exportjson"]["test.json", testdata]
```

It perfectly circumvents two of my problems